# Security Exception While Running TestNG test in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testng, testng-eclipse

Getting the below error while trying to run the  TestNG test in Eclipse Neon . Seems like there is some sort signed content in jar dependency which is blocking this .  have no idea what its though ..Any suggestions on how to fix this . Have never faced this before .

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:284)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:238)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:273)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:162)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.getTestNGVersion(RemoteTestNG.java:84)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:39)
[ServiceLoaderHelper] More than one working implementation for 'null', we will use the first one
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.internal.Utils.defaultIfStringEmpty(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.setHost(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:59)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:122)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)
```

Comment: Have you checked the use project testng jar option?  What version is your plugin and your jar?

Comment: Issue reported: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/263

Comment: which testng version are you using in your project .

Comment: thanks all ..will retry with a newer version of testng ..than 6.2 was having ...

Answer (score 1):

oh, I sort of got your problem, looks like you're using an pretty old version of testng (probably the 5.x), since TestNG eclipse plugin 6.9.12.201607091356, TestNG versions below 6.5.1 are not supported: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/blob/master/CHANGES.md#6910
So please upgrade your testng version.
Edit: since TestNG Eclipse Plugin 6.9.13.201609291640, the whole TestNG 6.x series are supported (including 6.0 to 6.5.1), while the TestNG 5.x still not be supported.

Comment: thanks all for all the input...I will try with a different version of testng and try this out ...

Comment: just FYI. in recent beta version 6.9.13.x of testng eclipse plugin, it supports testng version >= 6.0. but still, testng version 5.x not supported. https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/blob/master/CHANGES.md#6913